# Не работает форма голосования на php

Tags: php, post

Не могу понять, чего когда голосуешь, не отображается результат?

```css
<?php
$file = "golos.txt";
$a = file($file);
$i = 1; $fi = Count($a);
$n = 0;
while ($i <= $fi):
$a[$i] = trim(str_replace (" ","", $a[$i]));
$n = $n+$a[$i];
$i++;
endwhile;

if ($answer != "") { 
echo "<br>Спасибо, Ваше мнение учтено:"; 
$a[$answer]++; $n++; 

$rez = "Результаты голосования! ".$a[1].
" ".$a[2]." ".$a[3]." ".$a[4];
$fp = @fopen($file,"w"); 
if ($fp) { $counter=fputs($fp,$rez); fclose($fp); } 
else { echo "Произошла ошибка записи результатов!"; }

} else { echo "<br>Результаты голосования"; }
echo "<br>Круто! - <b>".$a[1]."</b>";
echo "<br>Так себе - <b>".$a[2]."</b>";
echo "<br>Сойдет - <b>".$a[3]."</b>";
echo "<br>Это что-то страшное! - <b>".$a[4]."</b>";
echo "<br><br>Всего проголосовало: ".$n;
?>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Голосование</title>
</head>
<body>
 <FORM METHOD="POST" action="golos.php">
<TABLE BORDER=1><TR><TD><TABLE BORDER=0>
<TR><TD>Ваше мнение о сайте?</TD></TR>

<TR><TD><INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=answer VALUE=1>Круто!</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=answer VALUE=2>Нормально</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=answer VALUE=3>Мне все равно</TD></TR>
<TR><TD><INPUT TYPE=radio NAME=answer VALUE=4>Это что-то страшное!</TD></TR>

<TR><TD><INPUT TYPE=Submit NAME=vote VALUE="отправить"></TD></TR>
<TR><TD><INPUT TYPE=Submit NAME=result VALUE="смотреть результат"></TD></TR></TABLE></TD></TR></TABLE></FORM> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас пустая переменная **$answer.** Должно быть $_POST['answer'];

Файл index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Голосование</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="golos.php">
        <table border="1"><tr><td><table border="0">
            <tr><td>Ваше мнение о сайте?</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">Отлично!</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">Нормально</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">Мне все равно</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="radio" name="answer" value="4">Плохо</td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="Submit" name="vote" value="Отправить"></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="Submit" name="result" value="Смотреть результат"></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Файл golos.php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if(!empty($_POST)) {
    $answer = $_POST['answer'];
    $file = "golos.txt";
    $a = file($file);
    $i = 1; $fi = Count($a);
    $n = 0;
    while ($i <= $fi):
        $a[$i] = trim(str_replace (" ","", $a[$i]));
        $n = $n+$a[$i];
        $i++;
    endwhile;

    if ($answer != "") {
        echo "<br>Спасибо, Ваше мнение учтено:";
        $a[$answer]++; $n++;

        $rez = "Результаты голосования! ".$a[1].
            " ".$a[2]." ".$a[3]." ".$a[4];
        $fp = @fopen($file,"w");
        if ($fp) { $counter=fputs($fp,$rez); fclose($fp); }
        else { echo "Произошла ошибка записи результатов!"; }

    } else { echo "<br>Результаты голосования"; }
    echo "<br>Круто! - <b>".$a[1]."</b>";
    echo "<br>Так себе - <b>".$a[2]."</b>";
    echo "<br>Сойдет - <b>".$a[3]."</b>";
    echo "<br>Это что-то страшное! - <b>".$a[4]."</b>";
    echo "<br><br>Всего проголосовало: ".$n;
}
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, а ещё такой вопрос, можно сделать так, чтоб оно записывало, сколько уже человек проголосовало? А то отображается всегда 1.

Comment: Переписать алгоритм на более нормальный, все это можно было сократить. А еще лучше не городить велосипеды и использовать phpmyadmin